# Output greater than without the previous character

Tags: code-bowling, radiation-hardening

For each character in your program, the program with that character removed must produce a number smaller than the program with the next character removed. Your base program isn't required to do anything, and may be invalid.

An example submission could be `abcd`, where `bcd` outputs 1, `acd` outputs 4, `abd` outputs 5, and `abc` outputs 11.

Your output can be in any format allowed by default (e.g. list of digits, unary string, etc.), but all of your programs must output in the same format.

This is [code-bowling](/questions/tagged/code-bowling), so the *longest* code in characters, not bytes, wins.

Comment: "Your base program isn't required to do anything." Is it fine to be invalid?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, that's what I was going for, will edit to clarify.

Comment: Are negative numbers valid?

Comment: Are floats vaild?

Comment: @CursorCoercer Yes to both

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), \$\infty\$ characters

```
20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390525XY20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390525M₁BD.VÁ.V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZC7TYMBDIQ3iuzz@dUiWtoolCClSEXBBGE1NmGRn4MVaOksP@7u89v7y@vtehywqHV6M9fhSTfkZnlbswzRSFPPt3dinONYlEe1ERz69MT22MCmc@BF09EOuJ2YjGSPDAJN267FJi1BiSFG3RqkKvNy6@ptq2wiGLmUZvZox3yJmvXehGwzjO2LRtQ0l7H00KBagVyKpg5cRqXUBhGYjpULbLkXVtv80ddW/WZvgSmNAEXlVlTdSUF45YaS58IDonbECiMvz/9P/PMTn74@7g@Pp/Pn/XQ@jm8)

This technique is capable of generating arbitrarily long solutions, and given here is a 657 characters one.

When removing each character, this outputs

```
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390525000
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390524999
...
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390524679
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390524678
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390527
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390526
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390525
...
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390204
-20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390203
-3
01
625
997
998
20369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390526
203691417459121541025956170746023725010219798381481292613670424841878397808208758216407259824975285354781743274097692954052414823827468252380161076797065742343594758578468019426891795218753047192723687494394131876739715230394212416812027980179249247414629187458572126582167367825613839106425675453516593954592132878123905259
203691417459121541025956170746023725010219798381481292613670424841878397808208758216407259824975285354781743274097692954052414823827468252380161076797065742343594758578468019426891795218753047192723687494394131876739715230394212416812027980179249247414629187458572126582167367825613839106425675453516593954592132878123905270
920369141745912154102595617074602372501021979838148129261367042484187839780820875821640725982497528535478174327409769295405241482382746825238016107679706574234359475857846801942689179521875304719272368749439413187673971523039421241681202798017924924741462918745857212658216736782561383910642567545351659395459213287812390525
```

### Explanation

This code has a pattern of `<number>XY<number>M₁BD.VÁ.V`, when `<number>` doesn't have any equal consecutive digits.

If one of `₁B` is removed then the code will output `01` or `625` respectively. Otherwise, the number will be base256 decoded and then run as an 05AB1E. This code inspects the stack, to detect which character was removed, if it wasn't one of `.VÁ.V`, output the correct number, and exit.

If the first `.` is removed, then `V` saves the code to the `Y` variable, which we can also detect and output `998`.

If the first `V` is removed, we get `.Á.V`, where `.Á` rotates the stack, so this is detected by inspection of the stack.

Otherwise, we leave `10N+20, 10N+9` on the stack after the first `.V`:

- If the `Á` was removed, then `10N+9` is executed and returns itself.
- If the `.` was removed, then `V` pops the `10N+9` and `10N+20` is returned.
- If the `V` was removed, `Á` rotates the top number, so the output is `rot(10N+9)`.

This is what the number base256 decodes to:

```
)D g4Qi D21 S èOsθ.ï><₄ * -(Y2Ê+,q} ¤.ïi θ>,q}D30Sè` ›iD 30Sè€Sø€ËO sà ₄*-,qB} D30Sè `‹iD30 Sè€S ø€ËOsà- ,q }àDsÌ10*s 9ªJ0i     a a  }
```

This code isn't especially interesting, but notice that there are a lot of spaces there which were inserted by trial-and-error to make sure there aren't any equal consecutive digits (because in that case we can't know which was removed).

`<number>XY<number>M` leaves `<number>` at top of the stack even after one character removal: If `M` was removed, then it's obvious, otherwise at least one instance of `<number>` must be valid, and it will be the bigger one, which `M` (which pushes the biggest number on the stack) will push.

Comment: Dang, clever, I really didn’t expect anyone to find an infinite solution

Answer (score 5):

## Wolfram Alpha, 12 characters

*Slight modification of the trivial solution in the community wiki, works for all languages that support superscript numbers as exponentiation*

```
10⁹⁸⁷⁶⁵⁴³²¹⁰
```

```
0⁹⁸⁷⁶⁵⁴³²¹⁰  -> 0
1⁹⁸⁷⁶⁵⁴³²¹⁰  -> 1
10⁸⁷⁶⁵⁴³²¹⁰  -> 10^876543210
...

10⁹⁸⁷⁶⁵⁴³²¹  -> 10^987654321
```

[Try it online](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%E2%81%B8%E2%81%B7%E2%81%B6%E2%81%B5%E2%81%B4%C2%B3%C2%B2%C2%B9%E2%81%B0)

Comment: Surely you mean ```9876543210⁹⁸⁷⁶⁵⁴³²¹⁰``` for 20 characters...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen [That does not work](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=876543210%E2%81%B9%E2%81%B8%E2%81%B7%E2%81%B6%E2%81%B5%E2%81%B4%C2%B3%C2%B2%C2%B9%E2%81%B0%3C9876543210%E2%81%B9%E2%81%B8%E2%81%B7%E2%81%B6%E2%81%B5%E2%81%B4%C2%B3%C2%B2%C2%B9)

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right!

Answer (score 4):

## Languages with implicit output - 10 characters

```
9876543210
```

876543210 < 976543210 < 986543210 < 987543210 < 987643210 < 987653210 < 987654210 < 987654310 < 987654320 < 987654321.

This works in languages such as Vyxal, Thunno 2, 05AB1E, Japt, PHP, the list goes on. You can edit in your favorite language here if you really want but it's not necessary.

Don't upvote this! It took very little effort. Instead, upvote clever answers in languages that don't abuse this trick.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 13 characters

```r
10^9876543210
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWaw0N4iwtzM1MTYyNDA0gYjeLlBWK83NTyzMSSxSKcxNzclKLFMpSi4oz8_MUSvIVSlKLS6wUlIA6gVqUuMCUgo2CIYjmMoTxDMA8AxgvDsyLg_GMwDwjGM8QYjPMVQA)

Languages (like R) that use `^` for exponentiation can gain 1 byte using a slight modification of [bsoelch's slight modification](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265806/95126) of [noodle man's CW answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265799/95126).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 14 bytes

```
10*9876543210H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/QQMvSwtzM1MTYyNDA47/1o4Y5Crp2Co8a5lqHWT/cuc9HxftYlwpYOCUzPbOkGCjDdXRygNvhdi6gIFg7UCNQ9PByh0cb13k93DlNJfI/AA)

Based on [@DominicVanEssen’s R solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265821/42248) in turn based on [@bsoelch’s Wolfram Alpha solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265806/42248). However, now adds one extra monad (`H`) to the end.

Note the TIO link shows all possible ways of removing a byte but is based on a shorter version of the code since the massive exponentiation times out. Given enough compute and memory it would work as intended.